# difference between clean and clean working directory in Eclipse WTP with Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am using Eclipse for Java web development. I have WTP and Tomcat installed. I run Tomcat via Eclipse (which is a pretty standard configuration).

What I want to understand is that:

When you right click on a server in the Servers tab, it gives you two options:

1. Clean
2. Clean Working Directory

Not much information could be found on Google. People are blindly choosing "Clean". Could someone please explain the difference between the two options?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Clean: Purges all webapps and redeploys them (don't do this while the Tomcat instance is running)

Clean working dir: Cleans out Tomcat's work dir, e.g., where compiled JSPs go. See [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/87174/Tomcat/Purpose-work-directory-Tomcat).

Comment: One question : It seems that you can clean the working directory when Tomcat is running. When you do that, does tomcat put the jsp, class files again into the directory again ? Or do you need to restart the server ?

Comment: You can do that while the instance is running. You will lose all already compiled JSPs and other stuff. There is no need to restart the server. When a JSP is called, it gets recompiled. Compiled classes always reside in `WEB-INF/classes` and have to be provided by *you*. Generally, a server restart is necessary, when you tamper files in `$CATALINA_*/lib` or `conf`.

Comment: Just to be explicit for posterity: `Clean` also cleans out the Tomcat working directory (i.e., if I run `Clean`, it would be redundant to run `Clean Tomcat working directory`), right?

Comment: when `clean` should be used (instead of `publish`) ?

Comment: @ThariqNugrohotomo. In rare cases when you have stale files or locked files not being published properly. Sometimes Eclipse simply forgets to publish JARs and Tomcat quits with `ClassNotFoundException`.