# Spring NestedServletException: Request processing failed exception is tiles CannotRenderException: ServletException including path

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tiles2

I am new to Spring,
I am using SPRING 3.0.4 REST MVC with tiles 2.2.2,
My question is very clear, when I tried to submit a request with simpler path's which I have configured in mvc-servlet.xml like /WEB-INF/jsp, it runs successfully, but when I tried to access path /WEB-INF/jsp/XYZ/xyz.jsp or /WEB-INF/jsp/ABC/abc.jsp, I get error, 
I have used tiles to create layout , I have two different roles for my app, one is user and second is admin, so obviously, I have created two dir under /WEB-INF/JSP/user and /WEB-INF/jsp/admin and put common files under /WEB-INF/jsp, so when I created a view (**check tiles config in code**) for user, I have used /WEB-INF/jsp/user, when access common files it works fine but when I submit a request to access files under /WEB-INF/jsp/user I got following error

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/user/layout.jsp'.

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/user/layout.jsp'.

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/user/layout.jsp'.
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

HERE IS LOG

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc] in context with path [/docuSaver] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/user/layout.jsp'.] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/layout/user/header.jsp (line: 21, column: 20) Attribute attribute invalid for tag insertAttribute according to TLD
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:408)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:237)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1265)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:875)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1539)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:475)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1795)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layout.user.layout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f1(layout_jsp.java:145)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layout.user.layout_jsp._jspService(layout_jsp.java:78)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1031)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:815)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:717)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Here is MY SPRING CONFIG

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.XXXX.common.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="2" />
    <property name="viewClass"> 
        <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView </value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/**/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean> 
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="3" />
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

HERE IS TILES CONFIG

```
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="userLayout" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/user/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/user/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/user/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
 <definition name="userHome" extends="userLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="XXXX" />
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/user/menu.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/user/body.jsp" />
</definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

Here is my WEB XML CONFIG

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/user/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/jsp/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/jsp/user/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

HERE IS MY JSP PAGE

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>

<html>
      <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" /></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td height="30"><tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="250"><tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><tiles:insertAttribute name="body" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="30"><tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, when I try to use the userLayout, it gives me status 500 exeception, It seems, I can only put my jsp pages under /WEB-INF/jsp directory as it is configured in spring at internalViewResolver, because when I created a layout in tiles with all jsp pages under /WEB-INF/jsp , it runs successfully, but when I created a folder and /WEB-INF/jsp/folderName/jspPAGE.jsp, spring start creating problem and it seems spring framework is fighting for finding out deeper path like /WEB-INF/jsp/folder/...
So, can some one tell me how to enable spring to find out more path inside the specified path,
Also I have a configuration for JSON and XML in spring config which I have not mentioned for simply reduce the code amount

Comment: I have added my jsp page as well, please check it

Comment: your tiles layout jsp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your header.jsp page, I think you have some tiles attribute on that page.
Try removing those and it will resolve your problem

Answer (score 3):

By using the `Order` property for `viewresolvers` it can be solved..

In your controller, if the return value is `userHome`, spring goes to tiles configuration. Otherwise it gives an exception, because, Spring first looks for pages under `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver` in your configuration. If it is not found, it throws an `Exception`. So define property for both `view Resolvers` and for `tiles resolver` gives min value than other resolver.

So, spring first looking in tiles resolver.

for tiles resolver:

```
 <property name="order" value="0"/>;
```

for `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver`

```
 <property name="order" value="1"/>;
```

Answer (score 3):

in header.jsp.
This line have the problem with your Tiles attribute, debug this and check for the page included into your tiles.xml

Answer (score 2):

What about reading the actual exception:

> JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/layout/user/header.jsp (line: 21, column: 20) Attribute attribute invalid for tag insertAttribute according to TLD

You have `<tiles:inserAttribute attribute="...">` in `header.jsp`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply...it gives me error on all the included pages i.e. on all tiles insert attribute. But if these header or footer pages when put under /WEB-INF/jsp dir, it works fine. So can you tell me a quick configuration.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean. Both your Tiles config and your layout JSP look fine. Can you show the `/WEB-INF/jsp/layout/user/header.jsp` file?

Comment: I have only div tag with hello header as content  only... no css no image

Comment: Please share the actual contents of that file in your question. The error is very specific about where the problem is.

Comment: I was saying that when the header.jsp, footer.jsp , body.jsp and menu.jsp put under /WEB-INF/jsp directory , everything works fine, but when same pages put under /WEB-INF/jsp/layout/user or any other directory which is under /WEB-INF/jsp/ than it start giving me exception like i have mentioned above in my question

Comment: <div> header page</div> this is what is in header.jsp page contains... now can you answer

Comment: If that is really the only content there, then you either are looking at a wrong JSP (the error says that it has at least 21 lines) or you have a problem with cleaning your deployment. Try to clean project and server working directory - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006461/difference-between-clean-and-clean-working-directory-in-eclipse-wtp-with-tomcat.

Comment: hey, thanks Pavel Horal, I checked it again when I came back to my office today, yes my header.jsp have some problem, I by mistake have same contents in header.jsp what I have in layout.jsp i.e. tiles:insertAttribute, I removed it and it works, and i also cleaned my project and server working directory as you suggested.