# spring tag lib not working

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

i have been reading similar post but couldn't make it work. I am using apache tiles and spring mvc together. Without using the form tags, the input elements are displaying but when i use the form tags, they disappear. I read that the tag lib should be added in each jsp even if you have created a common tile object. That's what i did and i got the error below. Can someone help me how to resolve this exception? thanks in advance.

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/common/baselayout.jsp'.

Comment: Without any code snippet that is causing this error, project structure, I doubt if anyone can answer this. I have a sample [Spring MVC Tiles](https://github.com/RawSanj/spring-tiles-sample-app) application that might be helpful for you to resolve this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring NestedServletException: Request processing failed exception is tiles CannotRenderException: ServletException including path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318594/spring-nestedservletexception-request-processing-failed-exception-is-tiles-cann)

Comment: thanks for all the comments, i appreciate your time. However, i found the issue was the attributes: readonly and required. Apparently, Spring does not want those. After removing those attributes, it worked.

Comment: @arn-arn you should write that up as an answer and accept it so others can clearly see it in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all the comments, i appreciate your time. However, i found the issue was the attributes: readonly and required. Apparently, Spring does not want those. After removing those attributes, it worked. Spring only allows the attributes that it defined.